# Fujitsu COBOL 3.0 - problem in executing

Tags: cobol

while running cobol prog in Fujitsu COBOL 3.0 an error is occuring saying that F3BIPRCT.dll is not found. what can be the problem.

Comment: I don't mean this smart or anything but were any of these helpful.  They seem to be what you are asking:  http://www.google.com/search?q=F3BIPRCT.dll+is+not+found

Answer (score 2):

Can you track down `F3BIPRCT.dll`?  If so, make sure the directory it is in, is in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: thanks eduffy :-) i changed the path variable and i could execute. I m using this software for the first time. i dont understand how to check the output. i clicked on execute and the window closed. nothing seem to appear.